# copying from hdfs to remote machine

Tags: hdfs, remote-server

Hi I am running this command on one of the end node of the hadoop cluster. 
I want to copy the data from hdfs to some remote machine. I can't store it locally because of limited disc quota in local machine. I want to run `hdfs dfs -get /data/abc remotemac/abc`

Comment: Is the remote machine you are talking about, another hadoop cluster? If so, you can use `distcp` for that.

Comment: its not a hadoop cluster. Its a remote standalone linux machine

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it directly however, you can look into the [Hoop](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/07/hoop-hadoop-hdfs-over-http/) and [WebHDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html) REST APIs. Hoop gives you access to HDFS read and write over HTTP/HTTPS.

On Hortonworks there is a blog about [WebHDFS HTTP rest access to HDFS](http://hortonworks.com/blog/webhdfs-http-rest-access-to-hdfs/).

There is an another solution using [sshj](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj). It is a pure Java implementation of SSHv2 allowing you to connect to a sshd server and use port forwarding, file transfer, etc. See details in the following reference:

Reference: https://blog.layer4.fr/2013/04/09/transfert-files-from-hadoop-to-a-remote-server-via-ssh/